# React-Native : Please correct my misunderstanding about how state works - Dynamic text inputs

Tags: arrays, react-native, state

This is 100% me just misunderstanding how state works in React-Native, and I'm hoping for an illuminating correction.

I've declared my state :

```
const [players, setPlayers] = useState(["",""]);
```

So there are two players by default, and neither have names. So far so good.

In my render(), this is where I spit out the text inputs :

```
{ players.map( (player, index) =>
  <TextInput key={index} type="text" style={styles.playerEntry} name={"player-"+index} value={players[index].name} onBlur={event => changePlayerName(index, event, players)} placeholderTextColor={color.greyPlaceholder} placeholder={appText.player[language] + (index+1)} />
) }
```

This works perfectly, and draws two text inputs with the correct placeholders.

my changePlayerName script works as well, and I've littered it with console logs to make sure :

```
This is me changing player 0's name to Michael
players :  (2) ['Michael', '']
This is me changing player 1's name to David
players :  (2) ['Michael', 'David']
```

So far so good. Now I want to add a new input. Please excuse the console logs. I'm an old dog with old tricks.

```
const addPlayer = () => {
  let playerState = players;
  if (players.length <= 4) {
    playerState.push("");
    console.log("pushed");
  }
  setPlayers(playerState);
  savePlayers(playerState);
  console.log('addPlayer playerState : ', playerState);
  console.log('players : ', players);
}
```

When I run this function from the add player button, I get a lovely play by play in the console:

```
players :  (2) ['Michael', 'David']
pushed
addPlayer playerState :  (3) ['Michael', 'David', '']
players :  (3) ['Michael', 'David', '']
pushed
addPlayer playerState :  (4) ['Michael', 'David', '', '']
players :  (4) ['Michael', 'David', '', '']
pushed
addPlayer playerState :  (5) ['Michael', 'David', '', '', '']
players :  (5) ['Michael', 'David', '', '', '']
```

So I've changed the state of players to be a 5 item array.

Unfortunately, no new text inputs are added at all. The updated state is never reflected in the array.map loop.

I HAVE tried making this a component and passing it props, but that doesn't seem to change outcome. If that's the way to do it, please let me know and I'll post that code.

I keep pouring over the RN docs, but I fear I'm not quite grasping how I'm supposed to use any dynamic data in an RN app :|

Comment: I'm also aware that this is wrong :

```
value={players[index].name}
```

But if I correct it to players[index], there doesn't appear to be a way to type in the textinput at all.

I'm quite confused at the moment >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `spread` syntax instead of `push` when adding new elements to an array. Treat arrays in state as read-only, so pass a new array to update state.

```
setPlayers([...playerState, ""]);
```

See [Updating Arrays in State](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I don't understand why, since I copied the array to another var, pushed to that, then saved that array over the original. I thought I was treating it like a new array.

It looks like I have a lot to learn about RN State yet! :)